# Dynamically create preference screen and sharedpreferences file

Tags: android

I have a preference activity and some list preferences whose options I need to populate dynamically so:

1. Can I populate these list preferences dynamically or do I need to create the whole thing (activity) dynamically?
2. If I do create the whole thing manually will the sharepreferences be update with my choices? (getDefaultSharedPreferences) and if not how can I get the choices I made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide settings for your app, you should use Android's Preference APIs to build an interface that's consistent with the user experience in other Android apps.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).

Comment: And regarding the sharedpreferences?

Comment: Each Preference you add has a corresponding key-value pair that the system uses to save the setting in a default SharedPreferences file for your app's settings. When the user changes a setting, the system updates the corresponding value in the SharedPreferences file for you.